# Creating a Multilevel dataframe row by row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

So, I have set some functions that retrieve data, and my idea is to create a DataFrame with the following structure.
Multi Level index, having 3 index named 'Date','Competition','Match'.
Multi Level column, in which I have 2 levels, with 2 values in the upper level and the same 8 column names for each one.

My guess is the best approach is looping to get every row and save it in a list, so once finished you only have to create the dataframe, but I'm having difficulties on how to actually do it.

To create the frame por the dataframe I do as follows

```
indx=['pts','gfa','gco','cs','fts','bts','o25%','po25/bts']
findx=[('h/a stats',x) for x in indx]+[('total stats',y) for y in indx]
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(findx, names=['tipo', 'stat'])
index2=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('date','competition','match')])
```

If I just do

```
fframe=pd.DataFrame(index=index2,columns=index)
>>[1 rows x 16 columns]
```

Which is OK, the frame has the desired structure, but if I try adding a dummy row from the beginning to check if it works

```
r=['11-12-11','ARG1','Blois v Gries',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

fframe=pd.DataFrame(r,index=index2,columns=index)
>>ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 19), indices imply (16, 1)
```

What am I missing? Why doesn't populate the dataframe? How should this be accomplished?

Comment: The error says you have 3 values in `r` more than required. Right?

Comment: reset_index and add it one by one, then set the index back

Comment: I've tried, but after reseting index append method still gives error. I make the list a DataFrame, and when using append I get ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'